# How to apply middleware selectively to reducers?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-middleware

With reduxjs-toolkit I define my store and middleware something like this:

```
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [reduxWebsocketMiddleware, adamBrownMiddleware]
});
```

However I only want to apply this middleware to certain reducers, not all. Specificially I want to apply websocket middleware to certain reducers, whereas in others I'm calling an API and this websocket middleware is not necessary.

It seems like adding another store to do this is an anti-pattern.

***So how can I apply middleware only for certain reducers?***

Comment: its not clear if you are repurposing your schleem so maybe check that too

Comment: The problem statement doesn't sound correct. Middleware don't "apply to reducers". Middleware form a pipeline around `dispatch`, and then dispatched actions eventually end up at the root reducer.  Can you provide further examples of what you're specifically wanting to do?

Answer (score 5):

You can always, in your middleware, check the `action.type` property (for example if it begins with `"mySliceName/"`) and otherwise skip the rest of the middleware.

As you don't really give an example what your middleware is doing and why you want to limit it, it's not really possible to give you any more input than that.

This could look like this:

```js
const middleware = api => next => action => {
  if (!action.type.startsWith("myWebsocketSlice/") { return next(action); }
 // normal middleware code here
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question to include reasons. Mainly because I don't want to apply websocket middleware to everything.

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. Just check the action type. That one `if` does not hurt any performance any realistically all middleware works that way.

Also, as Mark correctly mentioned: middleware applies to actions, not reducers.